# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available but entityManagerFactoryRef is set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to configure two H2 datasource. I tried dozen of tutorials but it still does not works. Now I have two configuration classes

First, default configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.yyy.xxx.repository",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DefaultJpaConfiguration {

    private final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    public DefaultJpaConfiguration(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        this.jpaVendorAdapter = jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.default")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory defaultEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(defaultDataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.yyy.xxx.entity");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("defaultPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(defaultEntityManagerFactory());
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultEntityManager")
    public EntityManager defaultEntityManager() {
        return defaultEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

And the second one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.yyy.xxx.adminPassword.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "passwordEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "passwordTransactionManager")
public class PlkPasswordsDatabaseConfiguration {

    private final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    public PlkPasswordsDatabaseConfiguration(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        this.jpaVendorAdapter = jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.adminPasswords")
    public DataSource passwordDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory passwordEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(passwordDataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.yyy.xxx.adminPassword.entity");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("passwordPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEntityManager")
    public EntityManager passwordEntityManager() {
        return passwordEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager passwordTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(passwordEntityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

Properties file:

```
datasource.default.url=jdbc:h2:mem:xxx_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
datasource.default.username=sa
datasource.default.password=

datasource.adminPasswords.url=jdbc:h2:mem:xxx_plk_passwords_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
datasource.adminPasswords.username=sa
datasource.adminPasswords.password=
```

The error I got say:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available`

But as you can see in configuration classes `entityManagerFactoryRef` is set.

Comment: when you have multiple datasources, EntityManager and PlatformTransactionManager, you must specify a primary one to spring. Add @Primary on one of the datasource, entitymanager and transactionmanager(doesn't matter which) bean

Answer (score 2):

when you have multiple datasources, EntityManager and PlatformTransactionManager, spring expects you to specify which one of it is the primary one. Add `@Primary` on one of the datasource, entitymanager and transactionmanager(doesn't matter which) bean

Comment: I added @Primary, but I got still the same error. I changed name to default.

Comment: Where did you put @Primary. Can you update the question